# Moving popup to back - C# UWP Universal Windows

Tags: c#, .net, canvas, popup, uwp

Is there a way to move a popup to back, so it does not always display on the front of the application?

I have a canvas that displays many shapes, which are resizable. To get the resize box I am using a popup, because it was suggested that the best way would be to use adorners, but these are not used in UWP, so the alternative are popups. It works quite well, but when I have another element overlaying my canvas and resizing was enabled on a shape, the popup elements (resize thumbs/nodes) are displayed on top of the element that should be overlaying the canvas. Is there a way to tell the popup that it should not display on a "higher level" than my canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Popup` control is intended to be displayed on top of all other content so it seems you're not using an appropriate control for what you are trying to achieve.

Without seeing more of your code and having a clearer idea of what you're doing (repro?) it's hard to suggest what you should do. However, I'd avoid resizing control that aren't on top of the viewable area or having multiple items in a resizable mode (or just with adorners displayed) at a time. Both of these should avoid what you're reporting.